# How to check Gmail API usage status in Google Console?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-developers-console, make.com

I'm sending automated emails from my account to my account, I'm using Integromat (now Make) and I've done all the necessary stuff in the Google Cloud Platform (or Console) to authorize Integromat. The scenario works and I send automated emails.

However when I go to check the usage status to see how many emails I have sent and how many I have left in the Google console, it shows no results.

For reference, I go here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/ to check the status, but all the graphs show no data whatsoever, despite the automated mails getting sent normally. I have the correct project selected when doing this.

Comment: Google cloud console stats are an estimate they are not actuate in any sense of the word.

Comment: @DaImTo so is there no way to check how many mail are left in the daily limit except making myself a counter?

Comment: The best way to see how many emails are left is to keep sending them until you get a quota error.  Google will tell you when you hit the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to see stats on any of your google usage quotas.  The Stats page on Google cloud console. Is at best an estimate and not real time in any sense of the word.

Either create your own counter, or just wait until you get the quota error. I normally go with the latter.